# Maximize the number of edges in subgraph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, linear-programming

We are given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and we want an algorithm to find a set of vertices $U$ to maximize the following quantity : $\frac{|E(U)|}{|U|}$ where $E(U)$ denotes the number of edges in the subgraph made with vertex set $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is known as *densest subgraph*. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph), there is a polynomial time algorithm based on flow networks, due to Goldberg. See Goldberg's technical report [Finding a maximum density subgraph](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1984/CSD-84-171.pdf).